# How validate completely invalid URL in Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, validation, url

How I can validate URL whitch looks like `https://&&&-%%$/` ?

`Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(potentialUrl).matches()` and `URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)` return `true` and it is not working for my situation.

Comment: What do you mean by valid? That URL is valid in terms of syntax. Do you mean you want to validate if the path part of the URL contains an acceptable domain? There are libraries for that, for instance https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/

Comment: @Tenfour04 Yes, I want to check that this domain is  acceptable. The syntax is correct in this case.

Comment: @Tenfour04 is it though? [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname) it says that "The Internet standards (Request for Comments) for protocols specify that labels may contain only the ASCII letters a through z (in a case-insensitive manner), the digits 0 through 9, and the hyphen-minus character ('-').".

Comment: @IvoBeckers The hostname is invalid. The URL as a whole is valid from the standpoint of containing the correct syntax pieces of a URL. A URL path is allowed to have those characters. In combination with the https scheme, this path doesn't make sense, of course. There may be other schemes where it's perfectly valid.

Comment: Sure, but I need validate user input text in EditText. Maybe there is some universal way to check that the URL does not contain extra characters?

Comment: @Tenfour04 what are the correct syntac pieces of a URL? Where is it defined? I would think that a valid hostname is part of the definition of a URL

Comment: I think it's getting into a semantic, opinionated argument for which I don't care one way or another (I'm just pointing out that a URL validator is justified in accepting the above example as valid), but a URL doesn't necessarily have to point to a web address or use an http/https scheme. It could even be your own invented scheme that's not registered with IANA. For syntax, there's [rfc3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986) that defines valid characters (see section 2.2)